# Python yfinance package: How to download financial ratios?

Tags: python, yfinance

I would like to download financial ratios, such as dividend yield, PE ratio, from finance.yahoo.com using the Python package yfinance (version: 0.2.31). I'm using the following code:

```
import yfinance as yf

ticker="MSFT"
stock = yf.Ticker(ticker)
stock.fast_info.get['marketCap']
```

Instead of market cap, I would also like to get trailingPE, trailingAnnualDividendYield, etc. which were available on previous version of yfinance. Any idea where this information is hidden in the stock object?